# Get response from retrofit API call

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to use retrofit2 to make an api call, here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Callback<List<Repo>>{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ApiCLient apiCLient = new ApiCLient();
        IApiService apiService = apiCLient.getApiService();
        Call<List<Repo>> call = apiService.getRepos();
        call.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Repo>> call, Response<List<Repo>> 
response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            List<Repo> repos = response.body();
        } else {
            ResponseBody a = response.errorBody();
            Log.d("asd", response.errorBody().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Repo>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("asd", t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any response. Also, debugger is not entering the onResponse or onFailure methods.

ApiClient class

```
private IApiService mService;
static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com";

public ApiCLient(){
    Retrofit retrofit = null;
    try {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mService = retrofit.create(IApiService.class);
}

public IApiService getApiService(){
    return mService;
}
```

And finally, IApiService interface

```
public interface IApiService {

    @GET("https://api.github.com/repositories?since=364")
    Call<List<Repo>> getRepos();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use this code :

```
public interface IApiService {

    @GET("repositories?since=364")
    Call<List<Repo>> getRepos();
}
```

for your interface .
and use

```
static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
```

for BASE_URL.